# How do I select an element within a frame without an ID in Python/Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm using Python 3.9, chromedriver 101 and the latest version of Selenium  I'm trying to select and click an element within a frame without an ID.  The HTML for the frame and element I want to click on are

```
<iframe title="false" class="k-content-frame" src="https://publisher.content2classroom.com/viewer.html#viewPublisherInstitutions?winId=ManagePublisherInstitutions" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">This page requires frames in order to show content</iframe>
...
    <span id="subpageBackTitle" class="subpage-back-title">&lt; back</span>
```

I have the following Python, which fails to select the element when it's visible

```
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
    ...
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".subpage-back-title")))
```

The resulting error is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:89: TimeoutException
```

What's the proper way to navigate to the frame and select/click on the element in question?

Answer (score 0):

To click on element inside a frame you need to [switch to the frame](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/frames/) first.

You can use any selector to switch to a frame. For the iframe `.k-content-frame` selector should work.

```
# Store iframe web element
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".k-content-frame")

# switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Your element
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".subpage-back-title")))
```

You can use `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` expected condition to wait for a frame. All available expected conditions can found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=expected).

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".k-content-frame")))
```